# python lxml Add a subelement keeping all the parent tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I have something like this:

```
<source>Some text <g>that is like this.<g> Needs </g></g>. <g> I want to keep this structure</g></source>
```

And I want to add a tag keeping getting this result:

```
<source><en>Some text <g>that is like this.<g> Needs </g></g>. <g> I want to keep this structure</g></en></source>
```

However, neither append, insert or subElement keep the structure of the parent.

```
from lxml import etree
xml = et.fromstring('<source>Some text <g>that is like this.<g> Needs </g></g>. <g> I want to keep this structure</g></source>')
root = xml.getroot()
element = et.Element('en')
root.insert(0, element)
print(et.tostring(root))
```

However it inserts an empty tag. I am not guessing how keep the whole structure of the parent like this:

```
<source><en />Some text <g>that is like this.<g> Needs </g></g>. <g> I want to keep this structure</g></source>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename the original root element and then append it to a new root element.

```
from lxml import etree

old_root = etree.fromstring('<source>Some text <g>that is like this.<g> Needs </g></g>. <g> I want to keep this structure</g></source>')

old_root.tag = "en"
new_root = etree.Element("source")
new_root.append(old_root)

print(etree.tostring(new_root))
```

Result:

```
<source><en>Some text <g>that is like this.<g> Needs </g></g>. <g> I want to keep this structure</g></en></source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Hope this will help.

[image]

Cheers!